# Changing ASP.NET tag formatting

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, formatting

When I drag a Label control to my document, I get the following code :

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

I prefer my code to look like the following instead :

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" />
```

How can I get .NET to do this by default? I looked in Tools -> Options -> Text Editor, where you'd expect to find it, but I couldn't find anything relevant there.

Comment: Perhaps I'm wrong, but I wouldn't expect to find that option anywhere. I believe the format is defined by the control itself. Some controls that don't expect to contain anything within the tags probably already do what you're looking for by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go back to Tools|Options|Text Editor, and expand the HTML node in the tree. Go to the Format node, and the click the Tag-Specific Options button. In the dialog that opens up, expand the ASP.NET controls tree and find asp:Label. You can set how you want the closing tag in the selector at the top on the right.
[alt text http://philippursglove.com/stackoverflow/tagspecificclosingoption.png](http://philippursglove.com/stackoverflow/tagspecificclosingoption.png)